# Devexpress grid with lookupedit datasource refresh

Tags: gridview, devexpress, refresh, datasource, gridlookupedit

I've got a form with a DevExpress grid view bound to a datatable DTable and a column that is a DevExpress lookupedit (RepositoryItemLookUpEdit) bound to a BindingList List.

At form load I initialize the datatable and the lookupedit from DB.

I also have another form with another DevExpress grid bound to the BindingList List used to edit and add items to the list of the lookupedit.

If I edit the items and close the form I update List and DTable (I have checked it while debugging), I have updated members in the lookupedit but the selected shown items of the column don't get updated.

What am I doing wrong? Thank you

Comment: Please, show us your current code.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my issue by reassigning the datasource of the grid at runtime as shown here
https://supportcenter.devexpress.com/ticket/details/k18490/how-to-properly-assign-a-new-datasource-to-a-grid-at-runtime

Thanks